# Sqlite3.DatabaseError only when I deploy

Tags: python, sqlite

### Introduction

I'm developing a python webapp running on Flask. One of the module I developed use sqlite3 to access a database file in one of my project directory. Locally it works like a charm, but I have issues to make it run properly on pythonanywhere.

### Code

Here's an insight of my `module_database.py` (both sql query are only `SELECT`):

```py
import sqlite3
import os

PATH_DB = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'res/database.db')

db = sqlite3.connect(PATH_DB)
cursor = db.cursor()

def init():
    cursor.execute(my_sql_query)
    val = cursor.fetchone()

def process():
    cursor.execute(another_sql_query)
    another_val = cursor.fetchone()
```

I don't know if that's important but my module is imported like this:

```py
from importlib import import_module

module = import_module(absolute_path_to_module)
module.init()  # module init
```

And afterwards my webapp will regularly call:

```
module.process()
```

So, I have one access to the db in my `init()` and one access to the db in my `process()`. Both works when I run it locally.

### Problem

I pulled my code via github on pythonanywhere, restarted the app and I can see in the log file that the access to the DB in the `init()` worked (I print a value, it's working fine)

But then, when my app calls the `process()` method I got a:

```
2017-11-06 16:27:55,551:   File "/home/account-name/project-name/project_modules/module_database.py", line 71, in my_method
2017-11-06 16:27:55,551:     cursor.execute(sql)
2017-11-06 16:27:55,552: sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed
```

I tried via the console to run an integrity check:

```
PRAGMA integrity_check;
```

and it prints `OK`

I'd be glad to hear if you have any idea where this could come from.

Comment: I think you may need to create a new cursor in each call to `init` and `process`.

Comment: I don't think so. IIRC as long as you don't do nested queries you can keep the same cursor and execute it when you need. And why would it work locally but not on pythonanywhere? I'll still try your idea tomorrow

Comment: You haven't said enough about your local and remote environments and how you do testing to say for sure, but I would guess that using a global cursor object in a multi-threaded environment has something to do with it.

Comment: From what I can tell, the Flask dev server is single-threaded by default, so that's one reason it might work locally and not when you deploy.

Comment: I'll run some tests tomorrow morning. Thanks for the advice. I'll keep you updated

Comment: Both of my environments are Flask, so they should be both single-threaded, shouldn't they ? Locally I use `flask run` and I set up the PythonAnywhere to run Flask too. Still, if that's a concurrence issue what kind of approach would you recommend ?

Comment: It depends on which PythonAnywhere account you have and how it's configured. Regardless, I would use SQLAlchemy instead of interacting with the low-level DB-API. The [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/) package makes it easy to integrate into a Flask app.

Answer (score 2):

a small thing, and it may not fix your specific problem, but you should always call `path.abspath` on `__file__` *before* calling `path.dirname`, otherwise you can get unpredictable results depending on how your code is imported/loaded/run

```
PATH_DB = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
    'res/database.db'
)
```